# How to compile a list of all objects with maximum value of a given attribute using stream?

Tags: java, max, java-stream, filtering

Say I have a list of `People` with attributes name and age. How do I get all instances of `People` that have the largest value for attribute age, using a stream?

Currently, I am using a two-step approach:

1) Finding the maximum value of age

```
int maxAge = group
        .stream()
        .mapToInt(person -> person.getAge())
        .max()
        .orElse(-1);
```

2) Creating a list of `People` with that age

```
List<Group> groupWithMaxAge = group
        .stream()
        .filter(person -> person.getAge() == maxAge)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

No worries, this works. However, consider the case that calculating the age is an expensive function. In that case, it would be nice if you could do it in one go, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use groupingBy with TreeMap as a mapFactory:

```
List<Group> list = people.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Group::getAge, TreeMap::new, toList()))
            .lastEntry()
            .getValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner way would be to use [`Stream.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max(java.util.Comparator)) as:

```
List<Group> groupWithMaxAge = group.stream() // Stream<Group>
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Group::getAge)) // Map<Integer, List<Group>
    .entrySet() // Set<Entry<Integer, List<Group>>>
    .stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(Entry::getKey)) // Optional<Entry<Integer, List<Group>>>
    .map(Entry::getValue) // Optional<List<Person>>
    .orElse(new ArrayList<>());
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to group and pick the max key (`age`):

```
List<People> peopleWithMaxAge = group.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(People::getAge))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.<Entry<Integer, List<People>>>comparingInt(Entry::getKey)
                .reversed())
        .findFirst()
        .map(Entry::getValue)
        .orElse(new ArrayList<>()); //empty list if original was empty
```

Comment: Is that, in your opinion, more effective? If I am not mistaken, you are still using two consecutive stream operations.

Comment: @MWB That depends. If we can reasonably assume that `age` is a low-cardinality field, then the second stream will deal with far fewer elements. One thing for sure is that this is better than 2 streams over `group`. And... if `getAge` is the expensive operation, it's not being redone.